# vue js- multi select : Select All / deselect All

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I need to have select all and deselect all functionality in vue multiselect https://vue-multiselect.js.org/

Here is the problem statement/requirement:

**MainArray=[1112,1113,1115,6667,6668,6669,1199,1144]**

when I type 111 then vue multi select will display only:

1112,1113,1115

Now I need an option to select all these three items with one click and need to add these items to

**selectedArray=[1112,1113,1115]**

When I again type 66 vue multi select will display

6667,6668 and 6669

Now I need to select all these three items, thus making

**selectedArray =[1112,1113,1115,6667,6668,6669]**

Now I search 111 again multiselect vue will display 1112,1113,1115. Now I need to deselect all thus making

**selectedArray=[6667,6668,6669]**

Again when I search 11, I vue multiselect will display

1112,1113,1115,1199,1144.

Here 1112,1113,1115 are in selected state and 1199,1144 are in deselect state.
Now when I click on select All[May be a check box or a clickable text] I need to select the remaining deselected items.
Thus making

**selectedArray=[1112,1113,1115,6667,6668,6669,1199,1144].**

Queries:

1. What is the best control I can choose for this Select All / Deselect All? Check box/ clickable text?
2. Best possible solution to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it’s very hacky, but you could make use of vue-multiselect‘s option groups: [optionGroups](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-option-groups)

So something like:

1. Listen on `@input` and set filter and set `group-` properties
2. use computed property `filteredArray` instead of `MainArray`, where you construct a list of a group, with the values which match the filter criteria, if there is no filter set, return the original array
3. Click on said filter group to select/deselect all children

Comment: Is this group-label provided in the documentation matches with 'filter group' in your 3rd point? So will it be like a constant group-label( select all deselect all) inside the multi-select and dynamic single array for group-value?

Comment: No? It is supposed to represent the current search entry, e.g. “111”